# Can Studying Generative Grammar Help Someone Understand the Word Order of a Language?

Tags: reference-request, generative-grammar

Let's say for example that someone wanted to learn French.  Would studying French's generative grammar help this person learn French word order?

Also, have there been any studies that teach L2 learners their target language's generative grammar in order to learn the language's word order?

Comment: Anecdotally, I know that some English language classes in Imbabura province, Ecuador, taught Aspects model tree-drawing in 1980. I doubt it was successful.

Comment: From what I've seen, studying advanced grammar is one of the *worst* things you can do as a beginner of a foreign language.  It can stunt your progress for years, and some people never recover.  (Source: went through English school courses in 90's Korea.)